# how to create 1 bit per pixel geotiff from binary file in python

Tags: python, raster, gdal

My question is: how can I create a geotiff that every pixel of witch represents 1 bit of a raw binary data that comes from input file?

thank you very much

Comment: Can you provide some code you have tried or more description of your input data?

Comment: my data is a signal recorded by a hardware. I want to display it on screen by black and wight pixels (with respect to 0 and 1 in the signal). this is for my signal processing course.

Answer (score 2):

In the creation options, use `NBITS` with the `gdal.GDT_Byte` data type.

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
ds_out = driver.Create(path, xsize, ysize, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte, ['NBITS=1'])
ds_out.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(myboolarray)
ds_out = None # Close.
```

See http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html, and note that it may not be read properly by some software (such as PCI Geomatica), but should be my most, and by GDAL subsequently.